# Use httpwebrequest to check if url exists

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm using a function to check if an external url exists. Here's the code with the status messages removed for clarity.

```
    public static bool VerifyUrl(string url)
    {
        url.ThrowNullOrEmpty("url");

        if (!(url.StartsWith("http://") || url.StartsWith("https://")))
            return false;

        var uri = new Uri(url);

        var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.Timeout = 5000;
        webRequest.Method = "HEAD";

        HttpWebResponse webResponse;
        try
        {
            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            webResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (string.Compare(uri.Host, webResponse.ResponseUri.Host, true) != 0)
        {
            string responseUri = webResponse.ResponseUri.ToString().ToLower();

            if (responseUri.IndexOf("error") > -1 || responseUri.IndexOf("404.") > -1 || responseUri.IndexOf("500.") > -1)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I've run a test over some external urls and found that about 20 out of 100 are coming back as errors. If i add a user agent the errors are around 14%.

The errors coming back are "forbidden", although this can be resolved for 6% using a user agent, "service unavialable", "method not allowed", "not implemented" or "connection closed".

Is there anything I can do to my code to ensure more, preferrably all give a valid response to their existance?

Altermatively, code that can be purchased to do this more effectively.

UPDATE - 14th Nov 12 ----------------------------------------------------------------------

After following advice from previous respondants, I'm now in a situation where I have a single domain that returns Service Unavailable (503). The example I have is www.marksandspencer.com.

When I use this httpsniffer [web-sniffer.net](http://web-sniffer.net/) as opposed to the one recommended in this thread, it works, returning the data using a webrequest.GET, however I can't work out what I need to do, to make it work in my code.

Comment: Have you tried using `GET` instead of `HEAD`? Could be that some webservers are actively blocking HEAD requests, though I'm not sure. I found this easy online tester for websites: http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html

Comment: The tool is good - helper me to resolve one issue. Amazon doesnt allow head requests, but does allow get requests. Marks & Spencer who are hosted on Amazon platform comes back with serice temporarily unavailable in both cases.

Comment: Okay, that just means the error is on their end or that you don't have an active session or something.

Comment: @Davio - thanks for the help. I've updated the thread, but still experiencing one issue that i've descrived. Can you offer any further advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the point of bieng able to validate all the urls without exception.

Firstly I took Davios advice. Some domains return an error on Request.HEAD so I have included a retry for specific scenarios. This created a new Request.GET for the second request.

Secondly, the Amazon scenario. Amazon was intermittently returning a 503 error for its own site and permanent 503 errors for sites hosted on the Amazon framework.

After some digging I found adding the following line to the Request resolved both. It is the Accept string used by Firefox.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
```